# Small caps font warning in beamer using biblatex

Tags: fonts, biblatex, warnings

Consider the following MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{silence}
\WarningFilter{biblatex}{Patching footnotes failed}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \fullcite{sarfraz}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This generates the warning:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/lmss/m/sc' in size <10.95> not available
(Font)              Font shape `T1/lmr/m/sc' tried instead on input line 28.
```

Is there a way to avoid the warning without using the `silence` package?

Comment: The real question should be: “How do I avoid small caps in citations?”

Comment: @LaRiFaRi I think that `fix-cm` is intended to be used with Computer Modern font and I'm using Latin Modern font.

Comment: @egreg I do want small caps in citations.

Comment: @petobens No, you don't, as there's no small caps font for Latin Modern Sans.

Comment: @egreg ah I get it now. So what's your recommendation? Is there a always use Latin Modern Roman (which I believe has small caps) in citations even when the text font is Latin Modern Sans?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Silencing the warning is not the answer: the output is incorrect because a serif font is used instead of a sans serif one. The problem is that the Latin Modern Sans fonts don't have a small caps variant.

Here's the output you get

[image]

which clearly shows the wrong font.

Redefine `\mkbibacro`, instead:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{silence}
\WarningFilter{biblatex}{Patching footnotes failed}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\renewcommand\mkbibacro[1]{{\footnotesize\MakeUppercase{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \fullcite{sarfraz}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Since this is used just for acronyms, the “wrong” font shouldn't be too evident.

Comment: Okay but suppose I want the last names in small caps. I should then use the workaround `\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\footnotesize\MakeUppercase{#1}}`?. What font or sans font (that has small caps) do you recommend to use in Beamer?

Comment: @petobens I recommend *not* to use small caps for sans serif fonts.

Comment: "a sans serif font is used instead of a sans serif one"? Did you mean just "serif font" for the first part?

Comment: `\mkbibnamelast` is only available for "*backwards compatibility with the legacy BibTeX name parts*" (see the [BibLaTeX documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf)). You should use `\mkbibnamefamily` here instead, in any case.

Comment: @Olivier You should address the comment to @petobens (add the username preceded by `@`).

Comment: @egreg True. Sorry about that mistake. I cannot edit my comment any more, though...