# Small caps in beamer lead to warning with french babel

Tags: beamer, small-caps, babel-french

I'm writing a presentation with beamer and trying to include a citation, but when I compile I get the warning

```
Font shape `T1/lmss/m/sc' in size <10.95> not available
(Font)  Font shape `T1/lmr/m/sc' tried instead.
```

I found [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203111/small-caps-font-warning-in-beamer-using-biblatex) about the same warning, whose solution consisted in adding

```latex
\renewcommand\mkbibacro[1]{{\footnotesize\MakeUppercase{#1}}}
```

in the preamble to fix this. But it did not work in my case. When I tried to create the MWE for this thread, I found what causes the error, but I can't find a way to solve it: when I use the `french` option for the package `babel` the names appear in small caps in the pdf and the warning is raised:

[image: see this picture]

but with the `english` option there is no problem

[image: see this one]

Here is the code:

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}   % with english it works

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\renewcommand\mkbibacro[1]{{\footnotesize\MakeUppercase{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \fullcite{sarfraz}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Bibliography}
  \printbibliography
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

An easy solution would be to keep the `english` option, but some characters are different with the two languages (such as quotation mark : *“ ”* in English, while *« »* in French).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Looks like your font simply does not support small caps, (which are used in French, but not English).

Comment: The error message is telling you that the font family you employ (Latin Modern) does not provide glyphs that combine sans-serif and smallcaps . Is switching to a different sans-serif text font an option for you?

Comment: the french localization of biblatex uses \textsc for the names, but your font doesn't support it. you could add (after begin document) `\protected\def\mkbibnamefamily#1{{\textnohyphenation{#1}}}`

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer, yes your solution worked well, thanks !