# Beamer: use sans-serif font for DOIs in list of references when using ISO960 biblatex style

Tags: beamer, biblatex

As before, I'm using `beamer`, `biblatex` and the ISO960 citation style (`style=iso-authoryear`). When a reference contains a DOI, the term ,,DOI`` itself is printed in small caps when using this style; in `beamer`, this uses a serif font that clashes with the default sans-serif font, and I would like to address this.

Here is an MWE:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8
%!TEX spellcheck = en_US
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[style=iso-authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{beamer-references-test.bib}
@Article{Hines2010,
  author    = {James R. Hines},
  journal   = {Journal of Economic Perspectives},
  title     = {Treasure {Islands}},
  year      = {2010},
  month     = nov,
  number    = {4},
  pages     = {103--126},
  volume    = {24},
  doi       = {10.1257/jep.24.4.103},
  publisher = {American Economic Association},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{beamer-references-test.bib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
        \frametitle{References}
        \nocite{*}
        \printbibliography
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]

Is there a suitable sans-serif small-caps font, and if so, how do I ensure it gets used here?

Alternatively: I'm not too hung up on the use of small caps as such. Is there a way to use regular capital letters for the term ,,DOI`` instead?

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/552709/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/203111/35864.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could redefine the `\mkbibacro` macro to use a smaller font size instead of small caps:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[style=iso-authoryear]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{beamer-references-test.bib}
@Article{Hines2010,
  author    = {James R. Hines},
  journal   = {Journal of Economic Perspectives},
  title     = {Treasure {Islands}},
  year      = {2010},
  month     = nov,
  number    = {4},
  pages     = {103--126},
  volume    = {24},
  doi       = {10.1257/jep.24.4.103},
  publisher = {American Economic Association},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{beamer-references-test.bib}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\mkbibacro}[1]{%
  {\scriptsize\MakeUppercase{#1}}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
        \frametitle{References}
        \nocite{*}
        \printbibliography
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or you could use a font which does have sans serif small caps:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[style=iso-authoryear]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{beamer-references-test.bib}
@Article{Hines2010,
  author    = {James R. Hines},
  journal   = {Journal of Economic Perspectives},
  title     = {Treasure {Islands}},
  year      = {2010},
  month     = nov,
  number    = {4},
  pages     = {103--126},
  volume    = {24},
  doi       = {10.1257/jep.24.4.103},
  publisher = {American Economic Association},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{beamer-references-test.bib}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\usepackage[sfmath]{kpfonts}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
        \frametitle{References}
        \nocite{*}
        \printbibliography
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]